# Visual Studio Code, Version 1.5.2.1: Cannot Run the Live Server

Tags: visual-studio-code

what's good?
So I've been struggling with trying to get the Live Server extension in VS Code to display a new chrome window whenever I want to display my code in a new webpage through Windows.

My monitor displaying both the "GO Live" and the "Open with Live Server" options:
[image: My monitor displaying both the "GO Live" and the "Open with Live Server" options]

I'm a new user, so there wis a link to the option I'm trying to select rather than an image. I also have the GO LIVE button on the bottom right hand side of my screen and I can also pop open my code on a new browser by selecting "Open with Live Server".

Nothing happens when I press either of those options. A new chrome window doesn't open. Below is a link to an image of my JSON settings of the Live Server extension.

My JSON settings for my Live Server installation:
[image: My JSON settings for my Live Server installation]